# How can you serialize an anonymous type using C# protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

```
using ProtoBuf;

    var anon = new { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Yan", Age = 29 };        

Serializer.Serialize(anon.ToString(), anon.GetType().BaseType);
```

Is it possible to serialize anonymous types in C# using protobuf-net?
The above is  a simplification of the scenario

really I have a stream of message signatures like (string message, anonymous type data, string secondMessage);

Comment: whats the output of your code example?

Comment: You might be able to use ExpandoObject. Look it up. Its a dynamic implementation of a dictionary which you can cast to a static type.